# Javascript leaving dropdown menu open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi all I am using a down menu on our website and it is all working fine except when you activate one of the drop-downs you can also activate any other drop-down menu without the previous one closing and it looks messy. Can anyone please suggest a way to make the previous menu close when you click on another one?

Here is my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function DropDown(el) {
            this.dd1 = el;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDown.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;

                obj.dd1.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }); 
            }
        }

        $(function() {

            var dd1 = new DropDown( $('#dd1') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                // all dropdowns
                $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
            });

        });

    </script>
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div id="dd1" class="wrapper-dropdown-5" tabindex="1">School Information
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="../pdf/schoolinfo/tariff_list_break_and_breakfast_16.pdf" target="_blank"><i></i>Break and Breakfast Price List</a></li>
<li><a href="../pdf/schoolinfo/bustimes-jan16.pdf" target="_blank"><i>  </i>Bus Timetables</a></li>
```

Many Thanks

J Tech

Comment: Please post the complete code so that it will be easy for us to help.

Comment: Try `$('.wrapper-dropdown-5').blur()`

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can see it in action

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't seem to work in that but you can see the layout of all the code in that https://jsfiddle.net/0md92hw6/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing a class, you need to blur the selects:

```
$('.wrapper-dropdown-5').blur()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for accordion menu . Here it's example. [Demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Accordion-Menu-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-metisMenu/#) [Download](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/jQuery-Accordion-Menu-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-metisMenu.html)

Comment: No Thankyou though it is just a button which dropsdown a list of links